# How do I avoid repetitions when combining two sentences with the same subject and verb?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following two English sentences:

1. The song is called "Name 1" on "Website 1".
2. The song is called "Name 2" on "Website 2".

I can combine these two sentences to read:

> The song is called "Name 1" on "Website 1" and "Name 2" on "Website 2".

The subject and verb are dropped.

Now consider the same two sentences in Chinese:

1. 這首歌在「Website 1」上線被稱為「Name 1」。
2. 這首歌在「Website 2」上線被稱為「Name 2」。

How do I similarly join clauses in Chinese if a different location is specified in the two clauses? Does it work the same as if no location was specified (i.e., just use 和)?

> 這首歌在「Website 1」上線被稱為「Name 1」和在「Website 2」上線「Name 2」。

The preceding text seems like it may be incorrect to me because the omitted verb occurs between the location and object.

It seems that I can also use 也, but that apparently requires repeating the verb, which I’d like to avoid to reduce verbosity:

> 這首歌在「Website 1」上線被稱為「Name 1」, 也在「Website 2」上線被稱為「Name 2」。

Comment: I do not think you can use "和" or "也" here. You just use a comma, or use "而".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **同时 (at the same time)** if you just want to state that the two are equally true.

> 这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，**同时**在「Website 2」上被称为「Name 2」。

Use **反而 (instead) or 而 (and/but)** if you want to stress the opposition between the two.

> 这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，**而**在「Website 2」上被称为「Name 2」。

You can avoid further repetitions by simplifying the second verb or using a synonym. I think you can also omit the location verb after the second 在:

> 而在 [ Website 1 ] （上）（它）叫 / 是 / 被称 [ Name 2 ]

Comment: I find it a bit strange that an adverb (同時) can be separated from a verb, but I think this or fefe's suggestion make the most sense in keeping the pair of clauses equal.

Comment: 同时 can also be a conjunction. Some accepted English translations are "moreover" or "furthermore".

Comment: Those words are adverbs. But apparently there's a concept called "conjunctive adverbs" in which an adverb functions as a conjunction.

Comment: Yeah, that might be it. IIRC 就 should be one of these too.

Answer (score 2):

Or simply, 这首歌在 *新浪* 上名为"你好"， 在*搜狐*上为"你好吗".

新浪 and 搜狐 are the names of websites.

Comment: Upvoted for the vocabulary. I'd rather keep the symmetry of identical verbs though since I apparently can't eliminate the second one.

Comment: @PatrickDark, from the symmetry standpoint, you can put 这首歌在 新浪 上名为"你好"， 在 搜狐 上名为"你好吗“ 。

Answer (score 1):

You can use '而 ~ 则 ' (and then) structure

> "这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，**而**在「Website 2」上**则**被称为「Name 2」

or simply use '则' (then)

> "这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，在「Website 2」上**则**被称为「Name 2」

You can also use '但 ~ 却' (but) structure

> "这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，**但**在「Website 2」上**却**被称为「Name 2」

or simply use '却' (but)

> "这首歌在「Website 1」上被称为「Name 1」，在「Website 2」上**却**被称为「Name 2」

Comment: Upvoted for the grammar points. I think these options put too much stress on the items being different when I want to simply indicate that there are multiple names, however.